# Как правильно вывести слэш через js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

День добрый! Имеется код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var json_content=[
  {
    "phrase": "Бабушка, скажите, пожалуйста, вы, может быть, поторопитесь? У нас-то время еще есть... А вот у вас, по-моему, не очень."
  },
  {
       "phrase":"Вывеска над кафе — '\u003cМы открылись\u003e'. Что-то не так. Где же '\u003c/Мы открылись\u003e'?"
  }
  ];

 $(function(){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * json_content.length);
        $(".joke").html(json_content[rand].phrase);
    });
});
```

Но при выводе на html страницу последней фразы получается:

```
Вывеска над кафе — '<Мы открылись>'. Что-то не так. Где же ''?
```

Хотя должно быть:

```
Вывеска над кафе — '<Мы открылись>'. Что-то не так. Где же '</Мы открылись>'?
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: `'&lt;/Мы открылись&gt;'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery зло.

```js
const json_content=[{
    "phrase": "Бабушка, скажите, пожалуйста, вы, может быть, поторопитесь? У нас-то время еще есть... А вот у вас, по-моему, не очень."
  },{
    "phrase":"Вывеска над кафе — '\u003cМы открылись\u003e'. Что-то не так. Где же '\u003c/Мы открылись\u003e'?"
}];
const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * json_content.length);
document.querySelector(".joke").innerText = json_content[rand].phrase;
```

```html
<div class='joke'></div>
```

Если всё же хотите использовать jQuery, то вместо метода html возьмите метод [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2), он экранирует всё необходимое

Answer (score 2):

У вас проблема в том что вы пытаетесь текст добавить как кусок `html` разметки, и во второй части вашего `json` есть слеш не экранированный сразу после символа `<`, и `jquery` пытается создать из нее `html` разметку. Если хотите поставить текст то нужно использовать метод `.text()`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="joke">
    
</div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var json_content=[
     {
       "phrase": "Бабушка, скажите, пожалуйста, вы, может быть, поторопитесь? У нас-то время еще есть... А вот у вас, по-моему, не очень."
     },
     {
          "phrase":"Вывеска над кафе — '\u003cМы открылись\u003e'. Что-то не так. Где же '\u003c/Мы открылись\u003e'?"
     }
     ];

    $(function(){
       var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * json_content.length);
           $(".joke").text(json_content[rand].phrase);
       });
   });

</script>
```

А если все таки у вас в тексте может быть и `html` разметка и вам нужно использовать метод `.html()` то надо разделить хотя бы пробелом символ `<` и `/` или символ `<` написать кодом вот так `&lt;`. Вот пример с методом `.html()`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="joke">
    
</div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var json_content=[
     {
       "phrase": "Бабушка, скажите, пожалуйста, вы, может быть, поторопитесь? У нас-то время еще есть... А вот у вас, по-моему, не очень."
     },
     {
          "phrase":"Вывеска над кафе — '\u003cМы открылись\u003e'. Что-то не так. Где же '\u003c /Мы открылись\u003e'?"
     }
     ];

    $(function(){
       var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * json_content.length);
           $(".joke").html(json_content[rand].phrase);
       });
   });

</script>
```